# A markov process which is not strong Markov (follow up)

Tags: stochastic-processes

This is a follow up discussion of
https://mathoverflow.net/q/43833

The examples there are interesting, but it seems that they all rely on an "ambiguous" transition function, i.e., there is some state $x$, $p(X_t\in A|X_0=x)$ may have different values, depending on how we arrived at $x$ in the first place.

My question: can someone provide an example of markov process which has well defined transition function but without strong Markov property?

Essentially, I am asking why continuity assumption in Feller process is necessary in proving the strong markov property.

Comment: What do you mean by "continuity assumption"?

Comment: @saz I mean the requirement that

Comment: @saz I mean the requirement that $P_tf(x)\to f(x)$ as $t \to 0$

Comment: @Jay.H I don't understand. None of the examples in the MO answer have ambiguous transition functions. In no case does $p(X_t\in A\mid X_0=x)$ depend on how we arrived at $x$.

Comment: @Jay.H I've posted an answer to what I **think** is your question. Let me know if it doesn't address your concerns.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland. Thank you very much for your replies, I will find time to digest some of the details-I never went through the strong markov proof, I guess it is about time to do it.   In regard to your example, I still have some question about $p_t(0,A)$, if we start from the stopping time( exponentially distributed as in you assumption), should the transition kernel be $\delta_t(A)$ ? Also, I am confused about the limit $lim_{x\to 0}$ you take, I thought in Feller process, we care about the continuity with respect to $t$ only. But as I said, I need some time to digest details. Thanks again!

Comment: @Byron Schmuland  Thanks again for your answers and comments, they are very helpful. About another example given by Andrey Recalo, I still think the transition function is not well defined for $p((0,0), A)$, can you please also comment on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that a Feller process is strong Markov, it is not the continuity 
of $P_tf(x)$ in $t$ that is important, rather the continuity in $x$. That is, we use that $P_t$ maps bounded continuous functions back into bounded **continuous** functions.

Here is a sketch of the usual proof: Let $T$ be $({\cal G}_{t})$-optional, and let $T_n$ be the standard dyadic approximations to $T$,
 so that, each $T_n$ is $({\cal G}_t)$-optional and $T_n\downarrow T$ on $\{T<\infty\}$.
 Fix $u\geq 0$ and $f\in C_b(E)$. Then, by the *Markov* property over $({\cal G}_t)$  we have 
 \begin{eqnarray*} \mathbb{E}(f(X_{u+T_n})1_{\{T<\infty\}})
 &=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(f(X_{u+k/2^n})1_{\{T_n=k/2^n\}})\\
 &=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}(P_uf(X_{k/2^n})1_{\{T_n=k/2^n\}})\\[5pt]
 &=& \mathbb{E}(P_uf(X_{T_n})1_{\{T<\infty\}}).
 \end{eqnarray*}

Since $P_uf$ is a bounded continuous function, and $(X_t)$ has 
right continuous paths,  letting $n\to\infty$ gives 
$$\mathbb{E}(f(X_{u+T})1_{\{T<\infty\}})= \mathbb{E}(P_uf(X_{T})1_{\{T<\infty\}}).$$

This shows that $(X_t)$ is a strong Markov process.

---

By way of  contrast, consider the Markov process $(X_t)$ on $E=[0,\infty)$ that (starting at the origin) spends an 
exponential amount of time at the origin, and then moves to the right deterministically at unit speed. It has transition kernel
$$p_t(x,A)=\cases{e^{-t}\delta_0(A)+\int_0^t e^{-z}\delta_{t-z}(A)\,dz&if $x=0$\cr
\delta_{t+x}(A)&if $x>0$.}$$

For a bounded, measurable $f$ on $E$ we have 
$$p_tf(x)=\cases{e^{-t}f(0)+\int_0^t e^{-z} f(t-z)\,dz&if $x=0$\cr
f(t+x)&if $x>0$.}$$

Notice that even if $f$ is continuous, $p_tf(x)$ will typically have a 
discontinuity at $x=0$ for $t>0$. The right hand limit is $\lim_{x\downarrow 0}p_tf(x)=f(t)$, while its value $p_tf(0)$ is a weighted average of $f$ 
over the interval $[0,t]$.

This process $(X_t)$ has continuous sample paths, is not Feller, nor is it strong Markov.

Comment: Using your formula for $p_t(x)$, it seems to satisfy all conditions of a Feller process.

Comment: So I am now totally confused. Also, there's this result for Feller process: it can leave a holding point only by a jump(see example, Revuz and Yor, page 110).

Comment: So, one question I have, the example you provide, are we sure it has continous path? If not, then $X_\tau$ might not be 0, and this will not really an example of Markovian but not strong Markovian. Haven't thought every carefully yet, apologize for any obvious errors that I do not realize yet.

Comment: @Jay.H For a Feller process, if $f$ is continuous then so is $p_tf$. That is not the case here, so $(X_t)$ is *not*, I repeat, *not Feller*.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Comment: @Jay.H Glad to be of help!